# Android Calendar Content Provider query keeps crashing

Tags: android, android-activity, cursor, android-contentprovider

I have a PhoneGap Application and I want to access the Android Calendar via the Content Provider. My PhoneGap JavaScript function can successfully call and return Java functions however I just haven't been able to get Content Provider calls to work. The app compiles without issues and run, but as soon as I call the related Content Provider function it hangs for a while and crashes. Below is a modified version of a Content Provider function I found:
    package com.george.myapp;

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class EventsInCalender extends Activity {
    //@Override
    public void onCreate() {
    //public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.event);       
    }

    public String getCal()
    {
        String cal_name = "createdstring";
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"),new String[] { "_id", "displayName" }, "selected=1", null, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
             String[] calNames = new String[cursor.getCount()];
             int[] calIds = new int[cursor.getCount()];
             for (int i = 0; i < calNames.length; i++) {
                  // retrieve the calendar names and ids                 
                  calIds[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
                  calNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
                  cursor.moveToNext();
              }
              cal_name = calNames[0];
              cursor.close();
        }
        return cal_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would follow this official documentation to handle Calendar Content Provider in Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html

1. Query calendars
2. Choose a calendar
3. Query events

Comment: Thanks, I have been through that but I see uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" and I know there is apps that access the calendar on older sdk versions, any suggestions?

Comment: Any calendar usage under API version 14 is not recommended by Google, therefore, I don't understand why a developer would choose to use those hacks. IMHO they just brings more problems and headaches.

Comment: Those apps that access calendars prior to API version 14 either read out the local database manually to get calendar events (hacky) or might use the Calendar Web Services of Google

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Context was the problem, needed to come from the main activity, think Android only grants the permissions to that activity

Answer (score 0):

You must add permission READ_CALENDAR to AndroidManifest.xml file.